# Feature selection in regression: are those features just correlated with outcome or are they causal?

Tags: features

When we get our variable importance plots in linear or logistic regression, we know that the features with more importance are correlated with our outcome.  Are they necessarily causal?

Comment: what do you mean by casual?

Comment: Like if X is selected as an important feature for predicting Y, is X necessarily causing Y?

Comment: no, nothing is necessarily causal. There are regressions in which sunspots predict stock prices. Causality is a matter of reasoning based on theory. Dont mix up causality and correlation!

Comment: Try explaining your question with examples and what have you done so far. Also, be clear, specific words.